# QED symbol on the same page as proof

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, amsthm

I'm using the `proof` environment from the `amsthm` package.  In some cases, the last line of a proof falls at the end of a page, but the QED symbol (the little white box) ends up on the following page.

Is there any way to guarantee that in each instance of `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}` in my document, the QED symbol will always be on the same page as the last line of the proof?

Here is an MWE which demonstrates this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}

\lipsum[1-5]
This is the concluding line of the proof.

\end{proof}

This line is on the second page, below the QED symbol.

\end{document}
```

Comment: An example? Does the proof end with a list environment or a displayed equation? In that case check for `\qedhere` in the documentation of `amsthm`

Comment: How full is this last line? If it spans the entire `\textwidth`, you may have to restructure the sentence in order to leave room for the QED symbol to fit on the same line.

Comment: @Werner I believe that it should be possible to use widow penalty to solve it in that case. @jamaicanworm: Could you please try adding `\widowpenalty=10000` at the very end of the last paragraph of your proof? I'm really not sure whether it can help and I can't test it now.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I edited the question to include an MWE which demonstrates the problem.  (Adding `\widowpenalty` as @tohecz suggested unfortunately does not help.)

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Removing the blank line before the end of your `proof` environment. If you want to keep this for readability purposes, then use a `%` in the blank line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you remove the blank line between `This is the concluding line of the proof.` and the `\end{proof}`, the problem disappears.

Comment: I have run into the same problem with no blank like before \end{proof} but with \end{equation} before \end{proof}.  Is there another solution to that problem?  Actually, I found the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128022/18

Answer (score 20):

it's probable that your proof ends with a list or a display environment.  since you're using `amsthm`, you can put `\qedhere` just before the end of that environment and the "tombstone" will be moved up onto the last line of the list or display.

**edit:**  with the addition of a (non)working example, it became obvious that the
problem was caused by a blank line before `\end{proof}`.  *never* leave a blank line
before `\end{proof}`; doing so will always result in the qed box being on a separate line,
and even possibly on the next page as in this example.

Comment: I have voted on this answer since it gives more general answer(in my paper I didn't leave blank line) - although from the OP's view the marked answer is better.