# Preventing the "end square" of proof environment to be alone on a newpage after an enumeration

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, amsthm

I have something like (with the packages amsthm and document class book):

```
\begin{proof}  
blabla  
\begin{itemize}  
\item blabla  
\item blabla  
\end{itemize}  
\end{proof}
```

The problem is, that ends on the bottom on a page and the square marking the end of the proof is alone on the next page. How can I avoid such behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and this answer! It works perfectly. I'll have a look to the starter guide.

Comment: related: [QED symbol on the same page as proof](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51781/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is what the command `\qedhere` is meant for with `amsthm`:

```
\begin{proof}
blabla
\begin{itemize}
\item blabla
\item blabla \qedhere
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}
```

it should be placed on the last line of the last `\item`.

it also works when the proof ends with display math, placed just before the `\end{...}`
command of the "main" environment.  (there may be some disagreement over the
vertical positioning in this case; for example, if the last line includes `cases`, the
box will be placed on the main baseline of that line, which is *not* the last line
of the `cases` environment.)