# Horizontal spacing in document class book

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, sourcecode, horizontal

Here is my document from the beginning:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  

\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
%\bibliography{references}


\begin{document}
```

And here is the part of my code in which I am trying to write the square at the end of a new line where the horizontal space before the square is empty.

```
We will have also, $\ker (r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a-1},$
and $\operatorname{coker}(r \lambda)_*\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{b-1}
   \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \square$\\
```

The problem of this code is that I get the square in the same line as the end of the proof and not in a new line. Could anyone help me solve this problem please?

Comment: Just leave a blank line before `\end{proof}` and you don't want to write `\square` or any thing, the `\qed` symbol is printed automatically.

Comment: @AboAmmar -- *Never* leave a blank line before `\end{proof}`.  That will allow a page break before the "tombstone".  See [QED symbol on the same page as proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard behavior of `amsthm` it is not necessary to add the square. The end of the `proof` will be marked with a small box aligned with the last line. Why do you need to add the square yourself?

You might add a `\newline` before `\end{proof}`, but it might confuse readers and also the square might end (alone) in the next page.

Also is available, from the same package, `\qedhere`, usually used to add the square --and then finishing the proof-- before `\end{proof}`, thus allowing to add a comment or a reference thereafter.

[image: c]

```
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{proof}
    The proof is by induction on $\ldots$.  
        
    The end of the proof is marked with a little box, (as an alternative to QED, \emph{quod erat demonstrandum}).   
    
    We will have also, $\ker (r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a-1},$
    and $\operatorname{coker}(r \lambda)_*\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{b-1}$
    \newline
%   \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \square$
    \end{proof}

    \begin{proof}
    To prove it by contradiction try and assume that the statement is false,
    proceed from there  you will arrive to a contradiction.
    
    \qedhere        
    \end{proof}

        
\end{document}
```

If you want all your proofs to behave that way, without adding a `\newline` each time, add to your preamble (dangerous, not recommended):

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
    \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
    \newline\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

**BECAUSE** it has bad behavior at the end of the page!

[image: d]

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why it's necessary to add the `\square`.  The OP is using `amsthm` which automatically sets the "tombstone", so if it is absent, something must be going on that isn't shown.  That should be investigated.

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain that this won't allow a page break before the "tombstone" (though I think it unlikely).  That should be checked, but unfortunately, I don't have time at present.

Comment: @barbara beeton Yes, the 'tombstone` jumps to the next page.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  You might try adding `\nobreak` to prevent that.

Comment: I have never seen this happening with me before "The end of the proof will be marked with a small box aligned with the last line."

Comment: I realized my problem, I have never used `\begin{proof}` and `\end{proof}` before.