# How would you change the qed box icon to just QED for a proof?

Tags: proofs

I'm new to LaTeX and was doing a simple proof:

```
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}

***arbitrary proof

\end{align*}
\end{proof}
```

when I recompile, I get the \qed box in the bottom right. What can I do to customize that and have it say QED instead, if that's a possibility?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which package -- `amsthm`, `ntheorem`, something else? -- you employ to gain access to the`proof` environment.

Comment: You might want to take a look at one of the answers to this question regarding the location of the QED when using an environment like `align*`: [QED symbol on the same page as proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51781)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you employ the `amsthm` package, you may achieve your formatting objective by redefining the `\qedsymbol` macro suitably.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{{\footnotesize\textsc{qed}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
bla bla bla
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```